# searching for reliable way to select iPhone 13 macro camera device

Tags: ios, objective-c, camera, native

i am developing an app using objc. I have to select the new macro camera, which is present in iPhone 13 Pro and 13 Pro Max. Currently i select my camera on all other devices with this code snipped:

```
    AVCaptureDeviceDiscoverySession *discoverySession = [AVCaptureDeviceDiscoverySession
        discoverySessionWithDeviceTypes:@[ AVCaptureDeviceTypeBuiltInWideAngleCamera ]
                              mediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo
                               position:AVCaptureDevicePositionBack];
    _captureDevice = discoverySession.devices[0];
```

But the documentation of the AVCaptureDeviceType does not provide any device type for the macro camera one: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturedevicetype?language=objc

Did apple forgot to add a type for the macro camera here, or is there something missing in the documentation?

Nevertheless i was able to select it with in my eyes very ugly and non stable method:

```
_captureDevice = [AVCaptureDevice deviceWithUniqueID:@"com.apple.avfoundation.avcapturedevice.built-in_video:5"];
```

I determined the string ending 5 only by testing against an existing device. I am also missing here some kind of documentation or ensurance that this will still provide me the macro camera, even after an ios update ;)

Does somebody know an reliable way to get the macro camera for in ios app development?

Comment: only for cross-reference, i posted the same question on apple developer foum: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/695438#695438021

Comment: did you find any solution to get the macro camera?

Comment: @Yuuu Only by the ugly non-documented way in the second code snipped linked above.

Answer (score 3):

You can use **AVCaptureDeviceTypeBuiltInTripleCamera** or **AVCaptureDeviceTypeBuiltInUltraWideCamera** and **videoZoomFactor=2.0**.

It help only on device with ultraWide camera

Comment: Is that behavior somewhere documented by apple? Does this work in general also for the new iPhone 14 line? Is there also a possibility to check before if a macro camera is present? It would be beneficial to get an general solution of picking macro camera, when present and fallback to standard main camera otherwise. Any ideas for that?

Comment: I test it on my iPhone 14 Pro. You can check UltraWideCamera or TripleCamera (one ultra wide, one wide angle, and one telephoto) by create AVCaptureDeviceDiscoverySession

`AVCaptureDeviceDiscoverySession * discoverySession = [ AVCaptureDeviceDiscoverySession discoverySessionWithDeviceTypes:[ NSArray arrayWithObjects:AVCaptureDeviceTypeBuiltInTripleCamera, nil ] mediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo position:AVCaptureDevicePositionBack ];
    if (discoverySession.devices.count == 0)
    {
        // no BuiltInTripleCamera
    }`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).