# iPhone macro photo/video capability detection

Tags: ios, avfoundation

Apple [advertises](https://support.apple.com/en-ca/guide/iphone/iphfaacf2eb0/ios#:%7E:text=Camera%20on%20iPhone%2013%20Pro,close%2Dups%20in%20sharp%20focus.) the iPhone 13 Pro, iPhone 13 Pro Max, iPhone 14 Pro, and iPhone 14 Pro Max as devices that can take macro photos/videos. How can I detect this feature from code?

The problem is that even an iPhone 13 Mini returns the `AVCaptureDeviceTypeBuiltInDualWideCamera` virtual device, and the `constituentDevices` contains a `AVCaptureDeviceTypeBuiltInUltraWideCamera`, but in fact you cannot take macro photos/videos with it it seems. So it likely comes down to something like

```
isFocusModeSupported(.autoFocus)
&& isAutoFocusRangeRestrictionSupported
```

or some similar requirement, but I don't seem to find any documentation that I could safely use (I only have one device to test, so other devices might not behave the way I think they would).

What I would like to do is to detect if I have the macro capability, and if I don't I would just fall back to the `AVCaptureDeviceTypeBuiltInWideAngleCamera` instead of the `AVCaptureDeviceTypeBuiltInUltraWideCamera` because that would have a too wide of an angle for me, and the user cannot focus when too close to the subject, so images turn out to be too blurry.

Ideas are appreciated! (I would not like to hard code device types to see if there is a feature, it's not maintainable)

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70112572/searching-for-reliable-way-to-select-iphone-13-macro-camera-device) post is related, but a bit older